# Gyroscopic Precession in Coaxial Helicopters

Tags: aircraft-design, helicopter, aircraft-physics, rotorcraft, theory

I'm trying to understand gyroscopic Precession in the case of coaxial helicopters. Obviously the effect still exists. But if gyroscopic Precession is a result of counter torque. Shouldn't the effect be canceled out in a coaxial helicopter?